# How to change the background color of weeks after the current week in Static Date Picker

Tags: materialize, mui-x

Right now i have the current week with a different color and the rest of the weeks with the same color.

[image]

with this code i can reproduce the above image:

```
<StaticDatePicker
    displayStaticWrapperAs={datePickerStyle}
    openTo={openTo}
    value={values}
    sx={{
        height: '100vh',
        overflow: 'visible',
        '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer': {
            background: 'rgba(255, 193, 95, 0.3)',
            marginBottom: '8px'
        },
        '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer:has(> .MuiPickersDay-today)': {                            
            background: 'rgba(0, 162, 170, 0.1)'
        },
        '& .MuiPickersSlideTransition-root': {
            height: '105vh'
        }
        }}
```

I want the weeks after the current to have the background white.
Does anyone know how to make the before weeks with the current orange and the after weeks with white/no color?

Thank you